# Unity camera trembling on collision

Tags: unity-game-engine, touch

The script works perfectly, exactly as it should, except when zooming too much and the SphereCast collides with the mesh. When it hits a mesh, I want the camera to just stop, and not try to go through the mesh.

[image: See demonstration here]

```c#
if(Input.touchCount == 2)
{
    Touch first = Input.GetTouch(0);
    Touch second = Input.GetTouch(1);

    origin = mainCamera.transform.position;
    direction = mainCamera.transform.forward;
    RaycastHit hit;

    if(Physics.SphereCast(origin, sphereRadius, direction, out hit, maxDistance))
    {
        inCollision = true;
    }
    else
    {
        inCollision = false;
    }

    if(first.phase == TouchPhase.Began || second.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
    {
        initialDistance = Vector3.Distance(first.position, second.position);
    }
    if(first.phase == TouchPhase.Moved || second.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
    {
        movedDistance = Vector3.Distance(first.position, second.position) - initialDistance;
        if(inCollision)
        {
            movedDistance = -Mathf.Abs(movedDistance);
        }

        mainCamera.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, mainCamera.transform.localPosition.z + movedDistance * zoomSensitivity * Time.deltaTime);
        initialDistance = Vector3.Distance(first.position, second.position);
    }
}
```

I tried to:

- Set `movedDistance` to `0` when SphereCast hits the mesh;
- Clamp `mainCamera.transform.localPosition.z` to `mainCamera.transform.localPosition.z`, but only when SphereCast hits the mesh, so the z doesn't zoom more than it's current value.

Comment: its probably "trembeling" because you move it back if its collided but in the next frame its allowed to move forward again

Answer (score 0):

As commented before you all the time move forward, collide, move backwards, don't collide anymore, move forward etc.

---

You could probably rather not move backwards but check if you **would** collide if you **would** move and do not move at all in this case:

```c#
if(first.phase == TouchPhase.Began || second.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
{
     initialDistance = Vector3.Distance(first.position, second.position);
}
else if(first.phase == TouchPhase.Moved || second.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
{
     movedDistance = Vector3.Distance(first.position, second.position) - initialDistance;

     // Only check until here if you WOULD collide
     origin = mainCamera.transform.position;
     var targetPosition = origin + mainCamera.transform.forward * movedDistance * Time.deltaTime * zoomSensitivity;
     direction = mainCamera.transform.forward;

     // only move if there WILL BE no collision
     if(!Physics.SphereCast(targetPosition, sphereRadius, direction, out var hit, maxDistance))
     {
         mainCamera.position = targetPosition;
     }

     initialDistance = Vector3.Distance(first.position, second.position);
}
```

---

From the example for [`SphereCast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCast.html) you can see that you could even take the `hit.distance` into account in order to at least move the camera the closest possible.